# Como declarar consulta select para comparar dos valores de las subconsultas

Tags: sql-server, select

Con la siguiente declaración genero la vista "SeccionEquipo"

```
 Create view SeccionEquipo as
 SELECT ca.idAsignatura, 
   ae.idEquipo, 
   ae.idPerfil, 
   tp.nombre AS NombreCargo, 
   asi.nombre AS NombreAsignatura, 
   c.idSemestre, 
   ca.idSeccion,
   s.jornada
FROM ArmarEquipo ae
 INNER JOIN TipoCargo tp ON tp.idCargo = ae.idCargo
 INNER JOIN Perfil p ON ae.idPerfil = p.idPerfil
 INNER JOIN PerfilAsignatura pa ON p.idPerfil = pa.idPerfil
 INNER JOIN Asignatura asi ON pa.idAsignatura = asi.idAsignatura
 INNER JOIN CargaAcademicaAsignatura ca ON asi.idAsignatura = ca.idAsignatura
 INNER JOIN CargaAcademica c ON ca.idPrograma = c.idPrograma
 INNER JOIN Seccion s ON s.idSeccion = c.idSeccion;
```

Luego filtro los datos que quiero obtener (para hacer mas comprensible mi problemática) con la siguiente declaración

```
 select * from SeccionEquipo Where idSemestre='2019O' and nombreCargo !='Dueño Idea'

 dAsignatura    idEquipo    idPerfil    NombreCargo
 Q2               2           5         Colaborador
 Q4               2           4         Jefe Proyecto
 Q4               2           5         Colaborador
 Q4               4           7         Jefe Proyecto
 Q4               4           8         Colaborador
```

Y

```
 select * from SeccionEquipo Where idSemestre='2019O' and nombreCargo ='Dueño Idea'

 idAsignatura   idEquipo    idPerfil    NombreCargo
 Q2                 2          3        Dueño Idea
 Q4                 2          3        Dueño Idea
 Q2                 4          6        Dueño Idea
 Q4                 4          6        Dueño Idea
```

Los resultados mostrados anteriormente son equipos de trabajo que realizan proyectos en la universidad a través de las asignaturas por lo que los integrantes siempre deben acompañar al "Dueño Idea". Esto quiere decir que los equipos de trabajo están compuestos de un "Dueño de Idea", "Jefe de Proyecto" (Líder) y "Colaborador"(ayudante). En cada semestre, a través de 2 asignaturas los alumnos deben generar informes y contenido, orientado al proyecto en cuestión, por lo que los alumnos e integrantes de los equipos deben estar siempre en las mismas asignaturas que el "Dueño de Idea". De lo contrario, se asumirá la dimisión del alumno. (por diversos motivos existentes: discusiones, reprobar una de las asignaturas, entre otros)

Ya con la noción del problema, explicare el caso. 
En los dos Registros anteriores vemos que existen dos equipos "idEquipo"=(2 y 4) 
e integrantes por equipo. En este caso "idEquipo"= 2 con los "idPerfil"=(3,4 y 5)
y el equipo 4 con los "idPerfil"=(6,7 y 8)

Como explique en el párrafo del contexto, los integrantes de cada equipo siempre deben acompañar a su "Dueño Idea" y en los registros se aprecia al los "Dueño Idea" estar en las dos asignaturas pero sus integrantes no. el único que si lo hizo fue el "idPerfil"= 5 del equipo 2 que se encuentra en la asignatura "Q2 y Q4" como lo hace su "Dueño Idea" de su equipo. Pero los demás no los hacen.

Entonces... En los registros hay 3 personas que debo quitar (4-7-8), y mantener al perfil 5 ya que esta con el dueño de idea en las dos Asignaturas.

Llevo dándole vueltas un par de días  para encontrar la solución y la única manera de poder lograrlo es preguntar si el "idPerfil" esta en esas asignaturas donde lo esta el "Dueño Idea" .

Lo mas cercano a lo que quiero es la siguiente declaración pero, una variable no puede contener mas de un dato.

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM SeccionEquipo a
WHERE a.idAsignatura =
(
SELECT b.idAsignatura
FROM SeccionEquipo b
WHERE b.idPerfil = a.idPerfil
)
  AND a.idAsignatura =
(
SELECT c.idAsignatura
FROM SeccionEquipo c
WHERE c.idEquipo = a.idEquipo
      AND c.NombreCargo = 'Dueño idea'
) and idSemestre='2019O'
```

Lo que declaro en la consulta es que las asignaturas del perfil sean las mismas que las del "dueño Idea"

A modo de prueba realizare las subconsultas (ubicadas dentro del "where") para detallarlo aun mas.

En este caso utilizare al "idPerfil" 4

```
SELECT b.idAsignatura
FROM SeccionEquipo b
WHERE b.idPerfil = 4 and idSemestre='2019O'

Resultado:Q4



SELECT c.idAsignatura
FROM SeccionEquipo c
WHERE c.idEquipo = 2
  AND c.NombreCargo = 'Dueño idea' and idSemestre='2019O'

Resultado:Q2 y Q4
```

Entonces es aca donde intento comparar los resultados generados sin lograr resultados. Fallando porque una variable no puede contener mas de un valor el cual necesito para comparar

Es fácil sugerir hacer un COUNT al "Dueño de Idea" y contar las asignaturas que el tiene pero, en general, los alumnos tienen mas asignaturas

NOTA: Los integrantes de un equipo no pueden existir en otro, a menos que dimita del equipo.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner las select que haces para conseguir los dos conjuntos de resultados que pegas al principio de la pregunta, por favor?

Comment: Sin entender muy bien lo que pides, porque no pones en la pregunta los nombres de las tablas, ni los campos que contiene cada una de ellas, una solución rápida pero chapucera sería poner TOP 1 en las subconsultas. Por ejemplo "SELECT TOP 1 b.idAsignatura
FROM SeccionEquipo b
WHERE b.idPerfil = a.idPerfil". No lo pongo como respuesta, porque no tengo nada claro que sea lo que estás pidiendo...

Comment: La solución de @angus esta excelente y funciona muy bien, de igual manera publicare mas contenido, al problema, para que mas gente se sume a la fiesta.

Comment: Listo! editado y bien explicado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entendí, hay que sacar a 4, 7 y 8 porque están en el mismo equipo que 3 (4) y 6 (7 y 8), pero no en las mismas asignaturas. O sea, mostrar sólo los perfiles que están como mínimo en las mismas asignaturas que el "dueño de la idea".

Acá va una idea de solución. Es, como proponías, contar las asignaturas, pero acotando antes el conjunto. Ojo, no está testeado (lo escribo directamente acá); lo importante es el enfoque. Suponemos que hay un solo dueño por equipo-asignatura. Cómo no sé si un perfil puede estar en más de un equipo, en las queries agrupo por equipo-dueño en vez de sólo por equipo o por dueño.

```
/* Primero, para cada perfil-equipo-asignatura, agregamos quién es
   el dueño de la idea */
;with CONDUENO as (select a.idasignatura, a.idequipo, a.idperfil, b.idperfil iddueno
                   from SECCIONEQUIPO a
                        inner join SECCIONEQUIPO b on b.idasignatura = a.idasignatura
                                                  and b.idequipo = a.idequipo
                                                  and b.nombrecargo = 'Dueño Idea'
                   ),
/* Todos los equipos-asignaturas en CONDUENO tienen dueño, así que podemos contar
   tranquilamente. Si un perfil tiene una asignatura sin dueño, ese registro no
   está en CONDUENO. Por lo tanto, cada perfil está en tantas asignaturas como su
   dueño, o en menos.
   Primero contamos en cuántas asignaturas está cada dueño:
 */
 CANT_POR_DUENO as (
   select idequipo, iddueno, count(*) c
   from (select distinct idasignatura, idequipo, iddueno
         from CONDUENO) a
   group by idequipo, iddueno
 ),
 /* Ahora contamos en cuántas está cada perfil: */
 CANT_POR_PERFIL as (
   select idequipo, iddueno, idperfil, count(*) c
   from CONDUENO
   group by idequipo, iddueno, idperfil
 )
 /* Y finalmente traemos los perfiles de la última tabla cuyo registro coincida
    en todos los campos con los del anteúltimo */
 select b.iddequipo, b.idperfil
 from CANT_POR_DUENO a
      inner join CANT_POR_DUENO b on a.idequipo = b.idequipo
                                 and a.iddueno  = b.iddueno
                                 and a.c        = b.c
```

El resultado de esta consulta incluye a los dueños mismos; tendrás que filtrarlos si no querés incluirlos.

Comment: Perfecto. Estuve dándole pruebas al código, lo probé con mas casos que pudieran suceder... Y en verdad, esta perfecto. Por mas que le diera vuelta, con mis conocimientos actuales, no hubiera podido llegar a ese resultado. Agradezco mucho tu ayuda master...  Aun tengo mucho que aprender

Comment: PD: El ultimo Inner join "CANT_POR_DUENO" cambienlo por "CANT_POR_PERFIL"  para que arranque ;)